# Maven project: The hierarchy of the type SpittrWebAppInitializer is inconsistent

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am using eclipse to implement the codes in the book "Spring In Action".

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

}
```

Then i have a error like this:

```
    "The hierarchy of the type SpittrWebAppInitializer is inconsistent"
```

But i have imported the necessary class in the library:
[Click here to see the Maven Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JToz.png)

Maven and SpringMVC is new to me and i'm confused about this error, please help me.

Comment: In what folder do you have your source? Should be in ```src/main/java/spittr/config```

Comment: Thank you, my source is in this folder. This error results from the version of spring as the first answer told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the versions of your spring jar packages are mess.

In your picture, the version of spring is 2.5.6.However the version of spring-mvc is 3.2.1.

try to update the spring to the lastest version,There is part of my pom.xml about spring.

```
    <properties>
       <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```